# External Dependency Manager in Unity installing Cocoapods succeeded but the pod tool cannot be found

Tags: ruby, unity-game-engine, build, cocoapods, iso

I try to make build on iOs with Unity. But has problem with Branch.io and (Header.h in xCode) file.
To resolve dependencies, it is suggested to use External Dependency Manager. It runs the cocoapods installation and gives the following error:

```
'gem install cocoapods --user-install' succeeded but the pod tool cannot be found.

It will not be possible to install Cocoapods in the generated Xcode project which will result in link errors when building your application.
```

My staff Mac **Apple M1 Pro. Unity 2022.3.10f1**:

```
 ~ % pod --version
1.13.0
 ~ % gem --version
3.4.10
 ~ % ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin22]
```

I would be grateful for any useful advice!

I set the environment variables in **$PATH**, and even launched Unity through Terminal, which partially helped, but the error remains and the project is built with errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok I think. You just need to open the Terminal at the build folder then type this:
**`pod install --repo-update`**